# sum of generalized harmonic numbers

Tags: number-theory, special-functions, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

For $\alpha>0$, let
\begin{equation*}
H_m^{(\alpha)}=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{k^{\alpha}}
\end{equation*}
What is 
$
\sum_{m=1}^n H_m^{(\alpha)}  ?
$
Does simply identity exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's $$\sum_{m=1}^{n} H_{m}^{(\alpha)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n-k+1}{k^\alpha} = (n+1)H_n^{(\alpha)}-H_{n}^{(\alpha-1)}$$

Comment: May I ask how you obtain the first equality?

Comment: How many times does $\frac{1}{k^\alpha}$ occur in the left hand sum? It occurs once per every $m$ with $k\leq m\leq n$. That means $n-k+1$ occurrences.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciated.

Comment: Is there any generating function for this sums?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Does this formula holds for $\alpha < 0$ ?